# When I Unlock my phone with my flutter app in the foreground, It bypass authentication

Tags: android, flutter, dart, authentication, lockscreen

My problem is that when I lock my Android phone with my flutter app in the foreground.

And then I wake the phone up, instead of taking me to the lock screen to give the password to unlock the phone, it takes me right to the flutter app, without any authentication.

How could this be resolved? Have anyone met this problem too?

Comment: could add some code that it can be reproduced?

Comment: I can't add code, because I can't find the issue that makes this bug

Comment: are you using something like wakelock ?

Comment: No, I dont use anything for this kind of thing

Comment: then i think it's issue of the android os rather than flutter app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add android:showWhenLocked="false" to your MainActivity in
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity 
     android:showWhenLocked="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest file. like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```